# Read ASCII file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I've got a text file and have to parse it in C++. I do it in this way:

```
std::string line;
std::fstream inputFile;

inputFile.open("test");

while(std::getline(inputFile, line))
{
  std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

inputFile.close();
```

This works fine, but German umlauts are shown as strange charaters. I converted the charaters to integer and found out, that the 'ö' in my file is 148 (0x94), but the character 'ö' is 246 (0xF6). Google says, that 148 is the ASCII code and 246 is UTF8. How do I switch the coding so that characters are converted correctly?

Is it possible to automatically detect coding?

Regards

Comment: I'm afraid the answers are you can't and you can't. C++ is agnostic about encodings, if you want to read a particular encoding you have to write to code to do this, or use a 3rd party library, it doesn't happen automatically. And there is no foolproof method (in any language) to detect how a file is encoded.

Comment: There are libraries to convert between encodings but you have to know what you are getting as input, and what you want as output.

Comment: It may help to know that you are not dealing with ASCII.  You are trying to consolidate _Unicode_ and a specific flavor of something called _Extended ASCII_

Comment: You are mistaken. "146" alone is not a valid UTF-8 grapheme.

Comment: Looks like Latin-1 or some variant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Comment: You read the german characters as ANSI (0-256), not as US-ASCII (0-127). 
Can you confirm that the file is coded in ANSI? Notepad++ is excellent in doing this check and is a free download. Where is the output? A console window? Can you confirm that?

Comment: Any byte that has a high bit set belongs to a multi-byte sequence in UTF-8. `ö` would be `C3 B6` or `6F CC 88` in UTF-8. You'll never get 0x94 in that case

Comment: I checked with Notepad++, it seems to be OEM 850 coding. It is an export from an accounting software. But how can I convert OEM 850 to UTF8?